# GDB doesn't print the output in signed decimal

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to use `gdb` to do some maths. Look at this two conversions

```
gdb$ p/x -8
$8 = 0xfffffff8
gdb$ p/d 0xfffffff8
$9 = 4294967288
```

Why in the second case `gdb` doesn't return `-8` instead of the unsigned value of the number?
Indeed, there is no difference at all between `p/d` and `p/u`

```
gdb$ p/u 0xfffffff8
$10 = 4294967288
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find the documentation for this, but it looks that default type for integer values in gdb is 64 bit signed integer. See this:

> (gdb) p/d 0xfffffffffffffff8
>   $7 = -8

So it interprets 0xfffffff8 as (int64_t) 0x00000000fffffff8, which is a positive value.

You are looking for this:

> (gdb) p/d (int)0xfffffff8
>   $9 = -8
>   (gdb) p/u (int)0xfffffff8
>   $10 = 4294967288

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems pretty obvious now. I also found out an alternative to your solution: `p/d -0xfffffff8`, that returns `$5 = 8`. It can be quicker (i.e. no need for Shift key) and you have only to remember to change the sign of your result again.